# Paginação de divs

Tags: jquery, css

Tenho uma `div` com uma `ul` e dentro 30 `li`. Dentro dessa `li` tem uma `img`.

Quero que quando tenha uma nova `li`, no caso a número 31, ele crie uma paginação, deixando essa nova `li` dentro da outra `div`.

Alguém já fez algo parecido?

O HTML está assim:

```
<div>
 <ul>
  <li><img.../></li>
  <li><img.../></li>
  <li><img.../></li>
 ...
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Você está buscando essas imagens dinamicamente através do banco?

Comment: Exatamente, tenho uma função que faz isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar jQuery para saber quando fechar uma `ul` e abrir outra:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("</ul><ul>").insertAfter("li:nth-child(3n+0)");
});
```

Nesse exemplo eu cortei o a cada 3 `li`. Você pode mudar o 3 por 30 que funciona da mesma forma.

Com esse código eu insiro o `</ul><ul>` depois do `<li>`.

**[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mapreuss/xj1hbfut/)**.

**UPDATE**

Conforme comentários abaixo, a prática acima não é indicada. É mais recomendado fazer segundo este exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/tgL1r5om/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var container = $('#container');
    var lista = container.find('ul').last();
    $("li").each(function(indice) {
        lista = indice > 0 && indice % 3 == 0 ? $('<ul>').appendTo(container) : lista;
        lista.append(this);
    });
});
```

Da outra forma o browser renderizava um novo `<ul>`; agpra a cada 3 `<li>` uma nova lista é criada.

Comment: Entendi o exemplo, obrigado. Porém, acho que o `nth-child` não funciona no IE8, estou certo?

Comment: No CSS não, mas no jQuery sim. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577674/how-to-make-internet-explorer-8-to-support-nth-child-css-element

Comment: `$('</ul><ul>')` não é uma boa. Na verdade, representa um `<ul>`, que [o browser insere solto dentro do outro](http://pastebin.com/e6Zb2h20) (o Chrome faz isso, achei estranho). Eu faria um loop, algo assim: http://jsfiddle.net/tgL1r5om/

Comment: eu não sabia disso @bfavaretto. vou atualizar a resposta com a sua, depois.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [`Quick Pagination`](http://www.kadunew.com/blog/jquery/paginacao-em-listas-html-com-jquery-quick-pagination)

## Exemplo

```
<ul class="pagination1"> 
    <li>1 - Item 1 de 25</li> 
    <li>2 - Item 2 de 25</li> 
    <li>3 - Item 3 de 25</li> 
    <li>4 - Item 4 de 25</li> 
    <li>5 - Item 5 de 25</li> 
    <li>6 - Item 6 de 25</li> 
....
```

Criando três exemplo de paginação

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("ul.pagination1").quickPagination(); 
    $("ul.pagination2").quickPagination({pagerLocation:"both"}); 
    $("ul.pagination3").quickPagination({pagerLocation:"both",pageSize:"3"}); 
}); 
</script>
```

Primeiro exemplo
Opção padrão mostrando 10 itens da lista e navegação na parte inferior.

> $(“ul.pagination1″).quickPagination();

Segundo exemplo
Mostrando 10 itens da lista e navegação na parte superior e inferior.

> $(“ul.pagination2″).quickPagination({pagerLocation:”both”});

Terceiro Exemplo
Especificados 3 itens na lista e navegação na parte superior e inferior.

> $(“ul.pagination3″).quickPagination({pagerLocation:”both”,pageSize:”3″});

Comment: Tinha visto esse plugin, porém ele não atendeu 100% a minha necessidade, mas valeu aí :D